# SQL - set property value to value of another property in same record

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume I have these 4 columns:

```
pid, id, name, placeholder
```

A few sample records from the sample table `myTable`:

```
pid, id, name, placeholder
1,   1 , hans, -
1,   2 , joe,  -
1,   3 , peter,-
```

Is it possible to copy all data from one column to another by using SQL? E.g. copy the content of `name` to column `placeholder`?

Expected Result:

```
pid, id, name, placeholder
1,   1 , hans, hans
1,   2 , joe,  joe
1,   3 , peter,peter
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET placeholder = (SELECT name
                   FROM myTable)
WHERE pid=1;
```

But I get `Error in query (1093): You can't specify target table 'MyTable' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: You don't need a subquery to set one field using the value of another field *of the same* record. Just use: `UPDATE myTable SET placeholder =  name WHERE pid=1;`

Comment: Is it a good idea to store same information two times?

Comment: @Jens, no, this is just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use below query

```
UPDATE `table` SET placeholder = name
```

You can also use where condition in this.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET placeholder = name;
```

*EDIT*
What & Why: It's a very simple procedure to copy one entire column to another in the given table.
And yes you could expand on it by adding a WHERE clause at the end, to perform the copy for only particular rows.

Comment: Do not only add code in your answe. Add an Explanation what and why